# Why is four-velocity a mixture of coordinates/ reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity

When we take the four-velocity
$$U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$
, we "mix components from two different referance frames". We take the x-components ($x^\mu$) from the "lab-frame" or some observers reference frame. Then we take the proper time from the objects reference frame ($\tau$). Why do we do this? For me it is not obvious how the space-time interval can remain invariant when we mix different reference frames in this way. I also don't have an "intuition" for what the "speed" is (I will get back to this).

The two four-vectors for positions are $x_{lab}^\mu=(ct,x,y,z)$ and $x_{prop}^\mu=(c\tau,0,0,0)$. So, in the proper frame, we have that the velocity (spacial) is $0$ and the velocity (temporal) is $c$. This I kind of get. But why do we not use
$$U_{lab}^\mu=\frac{dx_{lab}^\mu}{dt_{lab}} \qquad (1)$$
instead of
$$U_{lab}^\mu=\frac{dx_{lab}^\mu}{d\tau_{prop}} \qquad (2)$$?

My initial guess would be that (1) is invariant, but I see that $U^0=c$ if we use (1) and this results in $U_{\mu,lab} U_{lab}^\mu \neq U_{\mu,prop} U_{prop}^\mu$ because $U_{\mu,prop}U_{prop}^\mu=c^2-0-0-0=c^2$.

**Intuition:**  The component $U^0=\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ sort of makes sense to me. It is a way of saying: how fast does time move for the object in the lab frame (how fast do we "see" the object moving throgh time) relative to its proper time? It roughly speaking is a measure of the time dialation (right?). *But* I have no intuition for the spacial components. The speed we can measure in the lab is $U^\mu=dx^\mu / dt$ (for $\mu=1,2,3$). To me, it seems like $U^\mu=dx^\mu/d\tau$ is some abstract quantity that we can't measure. Am I wrong? What sort of physical interpretation can we have of this spactial speed (if any)? It is sort of like saying: "how far does the object move in the lab-frame, per unit of time in the proper frame", which I find confusing. To me, it is like saying: "if we have 5 apples and 5 people, how many people does each orange get?" It is unexpected and wierd in a way I find difficult to convey.

---

It is related to this question: [Are we using a hybrid coordinate system to define four velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595457/are-we-using-a-hybrid-coordinate-system-to-define-four-velocity) , but it is not quite the same.

---

Very much appreciate if anyone can help me understand this better. I hope the question was clear and convey my confusion in this matter.

Comment: One way of thinking about it is that $u^\mu$ is the ratio of $dx^\mu$ and $d\tau$. We already know $dx^\mu$ is a four-vector, so for $u^\mu$ to be a four-vector, it needs to be divided by a scalar. And $d\tau$ is a scalar.

Comment: That is, you shouldn't think of $d\tau$ as some quantity tied to a specific reference frame. Instead, it is a quantity that _all_ reference frames agree on, which just happens to have a nice and simple interpretation in the particle's reference frame.

Comment: (1) doesn’t transform like a four-vector; (2) does. Neither is “invariant”.

Comment: $\mathrm d\tau^2=\mathrm dt^2-\mathrm dx^2-\mathrm dy^2-\mathrm dz^2$ is calculate-able from lab frame, so it is not a mixture of coördinates

Comment: You shouldn’t think of the particle as another inertial reference frame; in general it will be accelerating.

Comment: *It is related to this question … but it is not quite the same.* It seems the same to me. In what way is it different?